# AWS code deploy error before install

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, devops, aws-code-deploy

I am getting following error while deploying using code deploy agent

/opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/6d3f114b-72a9-4d1a-9d65-1227b6839916/d-FWIG1AI1M/deployment-archive/appspec.yml

The problem is the appspec.yml gets created in folder inside the current deployment id.

Please advise as what is wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the error log? The place where appspec file is used looks good to me, according to http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/reference-appspec-file.html

Comment: Hi

This is the event log, the problem is that appspec.yml is getting created one directory deep than what codedeploy is expecting

No such file or directory - /opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/6d3f114b-72a9-4d1a-9d65-1227b6839916/d-TKSLQJD1M/deployment-archive/appspec.yml

Comment: This is the only error I am able to see on code deployagent deployments

Comment: Could you make sure when you tar the deployment files, appspec is always at the top level? Like some-jar-file/appspec.yml, where the some-jar-file is the revision that you are going to deploy